# Is it possible to test Desktop Applications using Protractor directly or via a third party tool?

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework, protractor, winium, winappdriver

I have an application built over angular (new version) and WinForms (legacy) which needs to be automated for testing. I had identified selenium (WinAppDriver + NgWebDriver) as the possible tool for use but the clients prefer Protractor, given the heavy use of Angular and considering future development.

Does anyone know if there is a possibility of integrating tools like Winium/WinAppDriver, etc with Protractor, so as to cover Desktop testing?

Comment: No, Protractor/Selenium  are tools designed for browser only.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using layered architecture approach you can add a desktop targeting project into your framework in order to perform desktop testing.

It's not integration Winium/WinappDriver *with* Protractor, it's using them *along* with each other, since they are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: Thanks for the revert, but I am under the dilemma on weather to move ahead with a Selenium+Winappdriver+ngWebdriver combo or a Protractor+Winappdriver combo. Which is better? As per my online research, I haven't found many using protractor with other tools.